# CSS/Bootstrap H4 not centered

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to centered a `<h4>` title in a bootstrap modal. This is my code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="
    margin-top: 40px">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Demander à être rappelé</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
       [body.....]      
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

It's work when i try on JSFiddle but not in my code ! I think it's caused by the WP is use (In conflict with bootstrap) but i'm not sure at all.

Comment: It's hard to tell what goes wrong without the CSS of a JSFiddle that shows the issue. Have you tried to use the developer tools of your brower to check which rule causes the title to render differently than what you expected.

Comment: You can share your working link where issue was coming?

Comment: Note: WP itself is probably not guilty here, AFAIK it doesn't apply styles on front-end by default. It's the theme you use that adds them. To isolate the rule, you could explore both versions in the developper tools and check for differences in style for your `h4`

Comment: @Jasha Yes i'm using chrome dev tool. The bootstrap class is recognized by the browser

Comment: @MinalChauhan Yes of course i will share the answer

Comment: @Kaddath I'm using Less to use Bootstrap only in this div. It's work well for the modal why not for text-center class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `justify-content-center` class to `modal-header`

```css
.modal  {
 display: block !important; // only for demo
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="
    margin-top: 40px">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Demander à être rappelé</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
       [body.....]      
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's work ! Thank's a lot !! But why only `text-center` doesn't work ?

Comment: because modal-header is `display:flex`, so it converts all his the child to flex item.

Comment: Yeah, i undestand. Thank you again !